# python dbf table.export | AttributeError: 'Db3Table' object has no attribute 'export'

Tags: python, dbf

I am working to use the `dbf` module for eventually editing a `dbf` file as part of a `shapefile` package. The `dbf` module out of the box seems far easier to use than the `dbfpy` module.

In any case, now I reach this point where I cannot export to a csv as the documentation says you can.  I am a novice python person so perhaps I am syntactically challenged.

```
import dbf
table = dbf.Table("C:\dev\SHAPES/the-database.dbf")
table.open()

table.export(filename="C:\dev\SHAPES/the-csv.csv", header=False)
```

This is a pre-existing database with names and coordinate extents.  What I am actually trying to do is programmatically rename about 5000 polygons within this `shapefile`.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Dont' forget to check the Help Center when you have time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you to progmatico, by looking into the test.py I found the feature for importing a csv, which demonstrated to me how to export to csv.  Here is my working script:

```html
import dbf
table = dbf.Table("C:\dev\SHAPES/the-database.dbf")
table.open(mode=dbf.READ_WRITE)

dbf.export(table, table.filename, header=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking into old documentation. I don't use dbf but I had a look into it. I suggest you download the tar.gz source code and take a look into `test.py`.

Search for `setUp(self)` first match and then for `export` to see some examples of usage.

Comment: Ok I downloaded the source code and am reviewing the documentation.  Thank you for pointing me there.